# Generate Random number between small decimal values C#

Tags: c#

I am struggling to find a solution that generates a random number from 0.0000000000001 up to 0.0001 in .NET.

I have been playing with the below but with no success:

```
Random r = new Random();
int rInt = r.Next(0, 100); //for ints
int range = 1000;
double rDouble = r.NextDouble() / range;
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this if you want to create uniformly distributed random numbers in the range from 0.0000000000001 up to 0.0001, i.e., (10^-13, 10^-4]:

```cs
var rnd = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(rnd.NextDouble()*(1e-4 - 1e-13) + 1e-13);
```

`rnd.NextDouble()` generates a random double in the range (0, 1]

`rnd.NextDouble()*(1e-4 - 1e-13)` generates a random double in the range (0, 10^-4 - 10^-13]

`rnd.NextDouble()*(1e-4 - 1e-13) + 1e-13` generates a random double in the range (10^-13, 10^-4]